# Namespaced nodes of the same name - content of the attributes needed

Tags: c#, xml

got this document:

```
<uniprot xmlns="http://uniprot.org/uniprot" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/    XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://uniprot.org/uniprot http://www.uniprot.org/support/docs/uniprot.xsd">
<entry dataset="Swiss-Prot" created="1986-07-21" modified="2013-10-16" version="88">
<dbReference type="GO" id="GO:0006412">
<property type="term" value="P:translation"/>
<property type="evidence" value="IEA:InterPro"/>
</dbReference>
<dbReference type="HAMAP" id="MF_00294">
<property type="entry name" value="Ribosomal_L33"/>
<property type="match status" value="1"/>
</dbReference>
<dbReference type="InterPro" id="IPR001705">
<property type="entry name" value="Ribosomal_L33"/>
</dbReference>
```

Right now, I'm using this to grab the inner text of nodes, which works fine...BUT...

```
XmlDocument XMLdoc = new XmlDocument();
XMLdoc.Load(Datapath);
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(XMLdoc.NameTable); 
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://uniprot.org/uniprot");
String NodeName = XMLdoc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:fullName", nsmgr).InnerText;
```

... I need to grab the attributes of  and whether type's content is GO or not and if so, get the following data of that exact node, namely id and value. Been thinking about and googling for this for several hours and I just lack the knowledge to get anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I managed to solve the problem:

```
            XmlNodeList Testi = XMLdoc.SelectNodes("//ns:dbReference", nsmgr);
            foreach (XmlNode xn in Testi)
            {
                if (xn.Attributes["type"].Value == "GO") 
                {
                    String Testilator = xn.Attributes["id"].Value;
                    String Testilator2 = xn.FirstChild.Attributes["value"].Value;

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [Linq to Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx), I find it a lot easier than XmlDocument and XPath queries, but that is at least partially personal preference.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by the "value" of each element with a type of "GO", but this should get you most of the way there. `goTypeNodes` will contain a collection of those nodes that have a type of "GO" with their ID and type values, and additionally contains the property elements underneath them, so if by "value" you mean the value of the property elements underneath them, it is trivial to get at that from there.

```
XNamespace ns = "http://uniprot.org/uniprot";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\SO\Foo.xml");

var goTypeNodes = from n in doc.Descendants(ns + "dbReference")
                    select new { Id = n.Attribute("id").Value, Type = n.Attribute("type").Value, Properties = n.Elements()};
```

By the way, your sample XML is missing closing tags for uniprot and entry.

Comment: Of course it is. I cut out only the important parts of that document.  That's what the complete one looks like: http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P30178.xml dbReference is in there about 20 times. I need to pick out the dbReferene nodes by its attributes. If the type attribute is set as "GO" (usually there are around 3-10 that contain "GO"), I want the rest of that node and the child node. Or to be more precise: If dbReference type == "GO" get dbReference id of that exact node and the content of value attribute of the child node property.